# No Vox Populi Badge awarded

Tags: support, badges

I have expended my 40 votes today and I am unable to vote on anything else for today. But still I am not awarded the Vox Populi badge. Can someone please check?

Comment: It takes for some badges at least 24 hours.

Comment: Are you sure you can't vote anymore? Your profile only says you've cast 31 votes today.

Comment: @Seth Yes I saw the descripancy and tried voting again after an hour, but still I could not vote, on neither a question, nor an answer.

Comment: @Luis ..24 hours already and still no badge :(

Comment: What do you mean by "could not vote"?

Comment: Means when I click on a voting button, the change reverts and a pop-up notification displays that I have used the maximum number of votes and I can vote again in x hours.

Comment: I was aware that we get 30 votes for answers and 10 additional for questions... But are these 10 bonus not available to be voted, and awarded only on the basis of the ratio of Q/A votes cast?.....seems overtly complicated.

Comment: Vote for questions and you will be fine.